# python bracket notation for dict to setitem method

Tags: python, dictionary

I know that for a **dict** D in python,

```
D = {0:1, 1: {2:3} }
D[0] = 1
```

is equivalent to

```
D.__setitem__(0,1)
```

what about below

```
D[1][3] = 4
```

although it's equivalent to

```
D[1].__setitem__(3,4)
```

I don't want to use bracket notation, how to do that?

Comment: How about `__getitem__` ?

Comment: As you shown? via `__setitem__` method. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: PSA: you can view all of the internal methods by `help({})` in a Python shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be like this: 

`D.__getitem__(1).__setitem__(3,4)`

Note that `__setitem__` called not for `D` variable, but for valirable retured by `__getitem__`

Comment: yeah that's obvious, in both ways we assume the child is dict type.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if you absolutely must avoid bracket notation for some reason:

```
>>> D.get(1).update([(3,4)])
>>> D
{0: 1, 1: {2: 3, 3: 4}}
```